# Entity framework POCO template missing (i am using visual studio 2010 professional )

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

When I create a `.edmx` file and I hit `Add code generation item` the POCO template is missing, I can only see `Entity Object Generator` and `Self-Tracking Entities Generator`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Visual Studio extension you have to install through the Extension Manager in the tools menu.  It's full name is ADO.NET C# POCO Entity Generator.